# When should you use traits vs parent/child relationship?

Tags: php

I have two controllers

```
login.php
auth.php
```

that both do security related checks (check to make sure user hasn't logged in too many times). they both call the following functions:

```
isThrottled()
```

i want to move these checks functions to a trait so I can share them between these two controllers above.

Is the best way to share the functions to use a trait? or to just put them in the parent controller? they both have the same parent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can reasonably use either in this situation, though I personally would choose to have a (probably abstract) parent class that the classes in login.php and auth.php extend.

Traits, to me, are for where you want a set of functions that you can use and reuse in multiple classes *that are not necessarily related*. I would argue that functions such as str_replace() and strstr() are methods in a global trait that is the PHP "object". You want those functions no matter what you're doing because they are useful tools in your tool bag.

Methods inherited from a parent are more focused, they provide reuse within a tightly defined scope. They're functions you wouldn't possibly need with a class that doesn't do the specific group of tasks that it is intended to deal with.

You wouldn't be doing anything wrong by using a Trait, but if you ask yourself the question "would I use isThrottled() outside of the specific model functionality of authorising a user" and the answer is "no" then it's probably a bit of an abstraction too far! In terms of maintainability and context that you can provide to future developers (or future you) I wouldn't sacrifice having that function in the middle of the code that it is related to.

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on the project, your code style, and of course what infrastructure is already in place.

Personally, I tend to go the way of either using Traits, or an interface, obviously the interface being used when I feel that other elements may be added or changed, and I would need to ensure (force) shared functionality across my app areas, without strict constraints on how the function works, or what it produces.

With the Trait being used for when I want to reduce duplication of code, such as in your instance. However this would be dependant on whether the method will have the exact same behaviour, input and return values across all the classes you will use it.

It honestly is never a 1 solution is the right way, and one the wrong way, however in this particular situation, I would use a Trait.

Hope that helps :)